# JMeter restart without plugin manager

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In JMeter GUI mode, choosing Plugin Manager, if I install/uninstall/upgrade I get a `Restart JMeter` button which will restart and open My current JMX with updated configuration/libraries

Is there an option without  Plugin Manager or changing plugin to restart JMeter and open My current JMX with updated configuration/libraries?

Usage: add new/updated library(jar) and check if it's working correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. as of JMeter 3.3, but you can ask for an enhancement request.

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html